# how to store the order of a list using html5 localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have an unordered list, sortable jquery ui,I want to know how to store the position of an

after it was dragged in the list.When the user refresh the page

stays where it was dragged.

Here is my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="uli">
  <li id="lit1" class="ui-state-default" style="width:100px; height:100px; list-style-type:none"><div>1</div></li>

  <li id="lit2" class="ui-state-default" style="width:100px; height:100px; list-style-type:none"><div>2</div></li>

  <li id="lit3" class="ui-state-default" style="width:100px; height:100px; list-style-type:none"><div>3</div> </li>

</ul>


<script>

$(function() {
    $( "#uli" ).sortable();
    $( "#uli" ).disableSelection();
  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize

```
$( "#uli" ).sortable({
  update: function( event, ui ) {
    var sorted = $( this ).sortable( "serialize", { key: "sort" } );
    localStorage['sorted'] = sorted ;
  }
});
```